# How to factor $z^3-3\sqrt{3}iz^2-9z+3\sqrt{3}i$ strictly via the method of grouping

Tags: complex-numbers, cubics

I really don't have much of my own attempt to show for this question. All I managed to get to was:

$$z^2(z-3\sqrt{3}i)-3(3z-3\sqrt{3}i)$$

By simply factorising. It is asked in the question to be completed via the method of grouping. I have been starring at this for far too long and don't see any way for this to simplify down nicely. The answer should be $(z-\sqrt{3}i)^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by grouping the terms as $$(z^3-2iz\sqrt{3}-3z)+(-iz^2\sqrt{3}-6z+3i\sqrt{3})$$
Then factoring out from the brackets:
$$z(z^2-2iz\sqrt{3}-3)-i\sqrt{3}(z^2-2iz\sqrt{3}-3)$$
$$=(z-i\sqrt{3})(z^2-21z\sqrt{3}-3)$$
$$=(z-i\sqrt{3})(z-i\sqrt{3})^2$$

et voila!

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion for applying the "method of grouping" when attempting to factor polynomials with degree higher than 2 , it may be helpful to look at a generic product first to see if one can obtain appropriate terms.

It is reasonable enough to start out by trying $ \ (z - pi)·(z^2 - q) \ \ , \ $ as you were looking at.  Since the last term is added, but is imaginary, we would choose one factor to use $ \ -pi \ $ and the other $ \ -q \ \ ( \ p \ \ \text{and} \ \ q \ $ being real).  The product is then
$$  (z - pi)·(z^2 - q) \ \ = \ \ z^3 \ - \ pi·z^2 \ - \ q·z \ + \ pqi \ \ . $$

We see that we would be able to "read off" $ \ pi \ $ and $ \ q \ $ directly with this choice.  But comparison with the given polynomial $ \ z^3 \ - \ 3\sqrt{3}i·z^2 \ - \ 9·z \ + \ 3\sqrt{3}i \ \ $ indicates that $ \ pi \ = \ 3 \sqrt3 \ \ , \ \ q \ = \ 9 \ $ cannot give us the correct "constant term".  So we must reject this choice of factorization as "too simple".

Since factoring the cubic polynomial will require a linear and a quadratic factor (and we have been told that "grouping" will work), what remains to us is to use a quadratic factor with a linear term, making our product $ \ (z - pi)·(z^2  \ \mathbf{+ qz} \  - r) \ \ , \ $ where we have again arranged for the constant term to be $ \ + pri \ \ . \ $  The product of factors becomes
$$ (z - pi)·(z^2  \ + qz \  - r) \ \ = \ \ \begin{array}{cccc}
z^3 & + \ q·z^2 & - \ r·z & \quad \\ \quad & - \ pi · z^2 & - \ pqi·z & + \ pri \end{array} \ \ \ . $$

To be sure, the sum of terms is more complicated, but there are sufficient clues to finding what $ \ p \ , \ q \ , \ r \ $ need to be.  We observe that the quadratic coefficient is now $ \ q - pi \ $ and the linear coefficient is $ \ -r - pqi \ \ , \ $ but the quadratic coefficient in *our* polynomial is purely imaginary $ \ ( \ -3 \sqrt3 i \ ) \ $ and its linear coefficient is real $ \ ( \ -9 \ ) \ \ . \ $  If $ \ p \ , \ q \ , \ r \ $ are all real, this could be conveniently arranged by taking $ \ q \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ $ which tells us immediately that $ \ r \ = \ 9 \ \ . \ $  Our factorization now looks like
$$ (z - pi)·(z^2  \ + 0·z \  - 9) \ \ = \ \ \begin{array}{cccc}
z^3 & \quad & - \ 9·z & \quad \\ \quad & - \ pi · z^2 & \quad & + \ 9p·i \end{array} \ \ \ . $$

We still have a problem, as this indicates that $ \ p \ = \ 3 \sqrt3 \ = \ 9p \ \ . \ $  So all three unknown coefficients cannot be real numbers.  What is left to try is to use an imaginary value for $ \ q \ \ , \ $ since we need to have the quadratic coefficient  $ \ q - pi \ $ be purely imaginary.  Thus,
$$ (z - pi)·(z^2  \ \mathbf{+ qi·z} \  - r) \ \ = \ \ \begin{array}{cccc}
z^3 & + \ qi·z^2 & - \ r·z & \quad \\ \quad & - \ pi · z^2 & - \ pqi^2·z & + \ pri \end{array} \ \ \ . $$

We note that this also keeps the linear coefficient real as $ \ -r + pq \ \ . \ $  This time, we have $ \ q - p \ = \ 3 \sqrt3 \ \ , $  $ pq - r \ = \ -9 \ \ , \ \ pr \ = \ 3 \sqrt3 \ \ . \ $  The difference $ \ q - p \ $ and and the product $ \ pr \ $ have a factor  $ \ \sqrt3 \ \ , \ $ but $ \ pq - r \ $ *does not*.  This would be the case if $ \ p \ $ and $ \ q \ $ each have such a factor and $ \ r \ $ does not.  If we write $ \ p \ = \ \mathcal{P}·\sqrt3 \ $ and $ \ q \ = \ \mathcal{Q}·\sqrt3 \ \ , \ $ the factorization is

$$ (z - \mathcal{P}·\sqrt3·i)·(z^2  \  + \mathcal{Q}·\sqrt3·i·z  \  - r) \ \ = \ \ \begin{array}{cccc}
z^3 & + \ \mathcal{Q}·\sqrt3·i·z^2 & - \ r·z & \quad \\ \quad & - \ \mathcal{P}·\sqrt3·i · z^2 & + \ 3\mathcal{PQ}·z & + \ \mathcal{P}·\sqrt3·ri \end{array} \ \ \ . $$

We are now able to account correctly for both the factors of $ \ i \ $ and the factors of $ \ \sqrt3 \ $ in the coefficients.  We are left to find values of $ \ \mathcal{P} \ $ and $ \ \mathcal{Q} \ $ for which $$ \ \mathcal{Q} \ - \ \mathcal{P} \ \ = \ \ -3 \ \ \ , \ \ \ 3\mathcal{PQ} \ - \ r \ \ = \ \ -9 \ \ \ , \ \ \  \mathcal{P}·r \ \ = \ \ 3 \ \ . $$

[Mercifully, these unknowns are all integers.]  We can do a little "experimentation" with small integers, or be more systematic by taking
$$ \mathcal{Q} \ \ = \ \ \mathcal{P} \ - \ 3 \ \ , \ \ r \ \ = \ \ \frac{3}{\mathcal{P}} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 3\mathcal{P}·(\mathcal{P} \ - \ 3) \ - \ \frac{3}{\mathcal{P}} \ \ = \ \ -9 $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ 3\mathcal{P}^3 \ - \ 9\mathcal{P}^2 \ + \ 9\mathcal{P}  \ - \ 3 \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ . $$
While it is a *bit* unpleasant that we obtain a cubic equation, we can see that $ \ P \ = \ 1 \ $ is a root(!), from which we quickly find $ \ r \ = \ 3 \ $ and $ \  \mathcal{Q}  \ = \   -2 \ \ . \ $  At last, we have the factorization
$$ (z - \sqrt3·i)·(z^2     - 2·\sqrt3·i·z     - 3) \ \ = \ \ \begin{array}{cccc}
z^3 & - \ 2·\sqrt3·i·z^2 & - \ 3·z & \quad \\ \quad & - \ \sqrt3·i · z^2 & - \ 6·z & + \ 3\sqrt3· i \end{array} \ \ \ . $$

This explains the "mysterious breaking-up" of terms in our polynomial shown in **David Quinn**'s answer.  This "factoring-by-grouping" is about *as difficult as it is possible* to make the problem and still be using integers in the solution (since the factors of $ \ \sqrt3 \ $ and $ \ i \ $ can be separated out), so your frustration is understandable.  The further step that could be missed is that the quadratic factor can be written as $ \ (z^2     - 2·\sqrt3·i·z  \  + \  3·i^2 ) \ \ , \ $ which makes it the "binomial-square" $ \ (z \ - \ \sqrt3·i)^2 \ \ . \ $  This leads to the final result **David Quinn** shows,
$$   z^3 \ - \ 3\sqrt{3}i·z^2 \ - \ 9·z \ + \ 3\sqrt{3}i \ \ = \ \ (z \ - \ \sqrt3·i)^3 \ \ . $$

$$ \ \ $$

This is not "factoring-by-grouping", but is something to try if the coefficients of the polynomial look like they may be suitable.  We learn that a "binomial-cube" looks like
$$ (z \ \pm \ c)^3 \ \ = \ \ z^3 \ \pm \ 3·c·z^2 \ + \ 3·c^2·z \ \pm \ c^3 \ \ . $$
The preponderance of factors of $ \ 3 \ $ and $ \ \sqrt3 \ $ in the coefficients in our polynomial suggest this might be worth the effort. We will want $ \   (z \ - \ c)^3 \ \ , \ $ for which we would have $ \ -3·c \ = \ -3·\sqrt3·i \ \ , \ \ 3·c^2 \ = \ 3·(\sqrt3·i)^2 $ $ = \ 3·(-3) \ = \ -9 \ \ , \ $ and $ \ c^3 \ = \ -(\sqrt3·i)^3 \ = \ -( \ 3·\sqrt3·i^3 \ ) \ = \ -( \ 3·\sqrt3·[-i] \ ) \ = \ 3·\sqrt3·i \ \ , $
all of which are consistent with our polynomial coefficients. So we confirm that the factorization is $ \ (z \ - \ \sqrt3·i)^3 \ \ . $